# python mysql Exception in command 'balance', (1048, "Column 'balance' cannot be null")

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python

the code is almost done but Im having problems with the database and the balance when it is 0

the script is simply connecting to coin wallet that uses RPC calls 
it send a call and then look at the balance and record in database and when some one deposit it send another call and register the new balance

ERROR

```
 [ERROR]   Exception in command 'balance', (1048, "Column 'balance' cannot be null")
```

database code

```
import pymysql.cursors
import warnings
from utils import parsing, output

config = parsing.parse_json('config.json')["mysql"]
host = config["db_host"]
   try:
port = int(config["db_port"])
except KeyError:
    port = 3306
    db_user = config["db_user"]
    db_pass = config["db_pass"]
    db = config["db"]
connection = pymysql.connect(
    host=host,
    port=port,
    user=db_user,
    password=db_pass,
    db=db)
cursor = connection.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

 #cursor.execute("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS {};".format(database))
 #cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {};".format(database))
 #conn.commit()

 #cursor.execute("USE {};".format(database))


 def run():
   with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter('ignore')
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
        snowflake_pk BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        username VARCHAR(37) NOT NULL,
        balance DECIMAL(20, 8) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (snowflake_pk)
        )""")
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS deposit (
        snowflake_fk BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        address_from VARCHAR(34) NOT NULL,
        address_to VARCHAR(34) NOT NULL,
        amount DECIMAL(20, 8) NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY (snowflake_fk) REFERENCES users(snowflake_pk)
        )""")
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS withdrawal (
        snowflake_fk BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        address_from VARCHAR(34) NOT NULL,
        address_to VARCHAR(34) NOT NULL,
        amount DECIMAL(20, 8) NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY (snowflake_fk) REFERENCES users(snowflake_pk)
        )""")
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tip (
        snowflake_from_fk BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        snowflake_to_fk BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        ammount DECIMAL(20, 8) NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY (snowflake_from_fk) REFERENCES users(snowflake_pk),
        FOREIGN KEY (snowflake_to_fk) REFERENCES users(snowflake_pk)
        )""")
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS server (
        server_id VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL,
        enable_soak TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (server_id)
        )""")
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS channel (
        channel_id VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL,
        server_id VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL,
        enabled TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY (server_id) REFERENCES server(server_id),
        PRIMARY KEY (channel_id)
        )""")
```

BALANCE code

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from utils import rpc_module, mysql_module

#result_set = database response with parameters from query
#db_bal = nomenclature for result_set["balance"]
#snowflake = snowflake from message context, identical to user in database
#wallet_bal = nomenclature for wallet reponse

rpc = rpc_module.Rpc()
mysql = mysql_module.Mysql()


class Balance:

def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot

async def do_embed(self, name, db_bal):
    # Simple embed function for displaying username and balance
    embed = discord.Embed(colour=0xff0000)
    embed.add_field(name="User", value=name.mention)
    embed.add_field(name="Balance", value="{:.8f} 
PHR".format(round(float(db_bal), 8)))

    try:
        await self.bot.say(embed=embed)
    except discord.HTTPException:
        await self.bot.say("I need the `Embed links` permission to send 
this")

 def __check_for_new_balance(self, user):
    balance = rpc.getbalance(user.id)
    mysql.set_balance(user, balance)

@commands.command(pass_context=True)
async def balance(self, ctx):
    """Display your balance"""
    # Set important variables
    snowflake = ctx.message.author.id
    name = ctx.message.author.name

    self.__check_for_new_balance(ctx.message.author)

    # Check if user exists in db
    result_set = mysql.check_for_user(name, snowflake)

    # Execute and return SQL Query
    result_set = mysql.get_user(snowflake)

    await self.do_embed(ctx.message.author, result_set['balance'])


def setup(bot):
  bot.add_cog(Balance(bot))
```